# LTSpice missing an SSR Component?

Tags: spice, solid-state-relay, ltspice

I want to simulate some circuits with SSR component but LTSpice does not provide this. From Eagle and KiCad I learned I can create my own component diagram. I'm not sure if I can do this also with a SPICE Application, because there are differences between and diagram and the functional aspect that SPICE simulates.

I have chosen the following SSR Component: "Sharp S202 S01" [Data-sheet: S202S01](https://cdn-reichelt.de/documents/datenblatt/C300/DS_S102S02.pdf), [reichelt.de](http://www.reichelt.de/S202-S01/3/index.html?&ACTION=3&LA=446&ARTICLE=15438&artnr=S202%20S01&SEARCH=S202S01).

The data-sheet offers the following diagram which looks to me like the internal circuit inside of the component. I think the Internal Connection Diagram is the functional circuit diagram which offers the same result as the standalone component S202 S01. I'm not sure whether I'm reading it properly.

[image: Internet Connection Diagram: Sharp S202 S01]

How can I solve this SSR Simulation with LTSpice (SPICE), to control 230V AC circuit with a 5V DC circuit?

Comment: Have you tried LTSpice support?

Comment: No. I'm not sure? Do you mean LTSpice support contact form or something else? I have not bought the software? I'm a beginner with this topic also a beginner in Electrical Engineering. Can you provide more information?

Comment: There is a Yahoo support group.

Comment: [This is the Yahoo group](https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/LTspice/info) that @Leon is talking about.  (As an aside, I have to say that the Yahoo groups have accumulated a wealth of knowledge over the years.  Unfortunately, Yahoo have made some UI "improvements" in the recent years, which made Yahoo groups less usable.)

Comment: Thanks LeonHeller & NickAlexeev. I hesitate to post same question twice on internet. I founded the group already but I was really missing the Hyperlink in @LeonHeller answer :) . Before I post on Yahoo Group I analyse the group. Could be that there is already an answer for my question in the group or in the files of the group. I suggest with the UI "improvements" of Yahoo.

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be? Can you maybe get away with some voltage/current controlled switches?

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm not sure because never worked with some voltage controlled switches. With this question I had also the intention to get deeper into SPICE, to understand what I can do in the case of "I miss a model". A missing model stops me and without and option how to handle and solve the missing model I can't done the simulation. One Option is "Substitution" like I learned in this discussion. But can we create the SSR model in spice?